# Reading in text from docx as paragraphs and saving paragraphs as string to a list

Tags: python, string, list, text, docx

I read in the paragraphs from a docx document, that works. Now, I would like to store each paragraph as a string to a list. I wrote the code below and ran it.

```
from docx import Document
sentences = []

document = Document('/path/to/*.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
    para = para.text
    sentences = sentences.append(para)
```

And got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Does anyone know how to get the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sentences.append(para)
```

Instead of:

```
sentences = sentences.append(para)
```

List.append() function returns None